# Synchronizing Video/audio with two different sources

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I have an issue with an very old film that I'm trying to recover. I have two source of the same film.

**Source 1** (from ffmeg -i):

```
Duration: 02:43:35.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1342 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (DIVX / 0x58564944), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 1200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 30k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

**Source 2** (from ffmeg -i):

```
Duration: 02:46:11.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1625 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 1431 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2014-06-22 12:06:22
  handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
```

What I would like is to take the audio from source 1 and video from source 2 and create a new file with them.

I have tried changing the source 1 to 30 fps and then using its audio with source 2's video but the audio 'fps' is really after sync after sometime. Perhaps my approach is wrong.

what's the best way to take the audio from source 1 synced with source 2's video?

Comment: You need to timestretch the audio to fit the change in duration. Generally you leave the audio alone and adjust picture to match but here you adjust the picture so be willing to sacrifice the "normality" of your sound (it will be subtly slower/faster but likely not noticeable). What's wrong with **29.97** anyways since it's an industry standard (NTSC)?

Comment: PS: For stretching with FFmpeg you want either **[Atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo)** or try **[Rubberband](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband)** depending what sound result suits you. I would try Atempo first since your FPS change is small. That is extract audio to MP3 then something like `ffmpeg  -i src1audio.mp3 -filter:a atempo="1.0333" src1new.mp3`. The `atempo` value is untested but either go `0.99xxxx` or go `1.0xxxx` since 1 is normal speed

Comment: Thanks lads... sorry for the delay. I've been overwhelmed with work so haven't had time to try these methods out.

I have no problem with going down to 29.97 fps as you said it's such a small difference. Seems like the most appropriate way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -i src2 -itsoffset 20 -i src1 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a new.mp4
```

This takes video from source 2 and muxes it with audio from source 1. No re-encoding takes place. The audio is delayed by 20 seconds i.e. the beginning of the audio from source 1 occurs at 20 seconds afte the video from source 2 starts. You can control the sync this way.

You can run a short command, first, to experiment with the sync value.

```
ffmpeg -i src2 -itsoffset 20 -i src1 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -t 300 test.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mulvya. Will this stretch the scr2 audio to match src1?

Comment: No. Just delays it.